# Check username and password in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, where-clause

this linq query

```
var users = from u in context.Users
            where u.UserEMailAdresses.Any(e1 => e1.EMailAddress == userEMail) && u.UserPasswords.Any(e2 => e2.PasswordSaltedHash == passwordSaltedHash)
            select u;
return users.Count();
```

returns: 1 even when there is nothing in password table.

how come?

what i am trying to do is get the values of email and passwordHash from two separate tables (`UserEMailAddresses` and `UserPasswords`) linked via foreign keys to the third table (`Users`).

**it should be simple - checking if email and password mach from form to database. but it is not working for me.**

i get 1 (for count) even when there are NO entries in the `UserPasswords` table.

is the linq query above completely wrong, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually everything is perfect with the query.

the problem was that i did not BUILD the solution before trying it.

what confused me was that it seems for the code behind i DO need to BUILD, but for the html/css i do not.

sorry

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `.Contains` instead of `.Any`